# GCC: __attribute__ ((format (printf, x, y)) does not seem to work when function is called using a variadic macro

Tags: c++, c, gcc, macros, variadic

*GCC version ntoarm-gcc (GCC) 4.4.2*

I've added 'printf' format attributes to all my functions that wrap printf() and co. They work perfectly fine except when calling the functions using a variadic macro.

```
class Log { [...]
    void log_fmt(LogLevel level, const std::string& funcName, const char_t * const logFormatStr, ...)  __attribute__ ((format (printf, 4, 5)));
[...] };
```

An incorrect direct call like

`log.log_fmt(Info, "test", "wrong %u", "type");`

yields warning:

`format '%u' expects type 'unsigned int', but argument 5 has type 'const char*'`

The same incorrect call using a macro yields no warning, however:

```
#define LOGI(MSG, ...) log.log_fmt(Info, __func__, (MSG), __VA_ARGS__)
LOGI("wrong %u", "type");
```

Can I get the warnings to show up in this case too? Have I made a mistake or is this intended behaviour?

Comment: macros don't check the type.they just replce

Comment: Have you tried `-Wall` and `-Wextra` parameters to `gcc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

struct log {
    static void logf(std::string, std::string, const char*, ...) __attribute__((format (printf, 3, 4))) {}
};

#define L(m, ...) log::logf("no", __func__, (m), __VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
    //log::logf("hi", "hi", "test %u", "hi");
    L("test %u", "hi");
}
```

works perfectly, in the sense that it gives the correct warning, like below:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:8:61: warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 4 has type 'const char*' [-Wformat=]
 #define L(m, ...) log::logf("no", __func__, (m), __VA_ARGS__)
                                                             ^
main.cpp:12:5: note: in expansion of macro 'L'
     L("test %u", "hi");
     ^
At global scope:
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-undefined-internal" [enabled by default]
```

So, I would guess that the problem is on the position parameters (you have put `4, 5` on your `format` attribute, when it seems that you should have put `3, 4`)....

Comment: 4, 5 is correct in the inital code. Note that yours is implemented as static member function while the original called the member function of the log object which adds the hidden `this` parameter.

Nevertheless the construct works as well with a nonstatic member function. @unbekannt: I can only assume you managed to hide the format attribute from the calling code somehow (multiple include files with one missing the `format`function attribute?).

Comment: @mfro, you are completely right about the `4, 5`. But it still works perfectly (giving the warning) to me, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5826ec98b97c3bcf)...

Comment: Inspired by Massas answer I've tried to get it working again in a minimal example. It did work. And it continued to work in the "real" code. How I hate it when that happens... Looks like I've indeed made some stupid mistake. Would it be OK to accept Massas answer as it lead me to trying again?